# Get the last item in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

The question is straightforward. How can I get the last item in a `foreach` loop? Now I know I can find it starting an index and counting the items in the collection, but I was wondering if there is more elegant way?

```
foreach (var item in Collection)
{
}
```

Comment: Do you have to do it in a loop? Seems pointless...

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil I didn't know I can get it using Linq.

Comment: @Vahid - Ah yea, Linq and I are bff. It'll do a lot for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `foreach` you can do that with [`Enumerable.Last`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.last%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var lastItem = Collection.Last();
```

[MSDN- `Enumerable.Last<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The Last(IEnumerable) method throws an exception if
>   source contains no elements. To instead return a default value when
>   the source sequence is empty, use the [LastOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: Thanks Habib, I knew there was an elegant way like this.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `Last`:

`Collection.Last()` - This will return the last item in the list.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with Collection.Last() but you could do:

```
foreach (var item in Collection.Reverse())
    ... item is last on the first iteration
```

but the real question is why would you do this.